# Dealing with timeouts on large queries

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am running into timeout issues with a very straightforward query.  It seems to be because it can potentially return a very large number of results.

It's working against a table that stores an edge list for a weighted graph:

```
CREATE TABLE Graph
    (Node1 int not null,
     Node2 int not null,
     Weight real not null,
     UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (Node1, Node2))
```

The query is simply searching for a particular Node1:

```
SELECT Node1, Node2, Weight from Graph where Node1 = @node1
```

The query plan is okayish - a nonclustered index seek and a RID lookup. Naturally I'm going to have to see if I can get that unique nonclustered index switched over to a primary key.  This table's huge (about 60 gigs, data and index) so I'm sure the disk is getting one heck of a workout.

I'm worried that won't entirely solve my problem, though.  The timeout happens after I've had quite a lot of time to spin through my `SqlDataReader`, and I'm not having any responsiveness issues with the reader itself - the server's being perfectly communicative.  I suspect the real problem is related to this note from the documentation for `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout`:

> This property is the cumulative time-out for all network reads during command execution or processing of the results. A time-out can still occur after the first row is returned, and does not include user processing time, only network read time.

It seems I'm getting the timeout on queries that return particularly large result sets, simply because it takes a while to transfer them over the network. Is there a better way to be doing this?  It seems there should be some way to say, "I only want a timeout in the event of an actual failure to communicate."

Comment: another option for speedup would be making a covering index for `Node1` to include (Node2, Weight). I would imagine that would make it significantly faster - also why don't you have a clustered index on that table?

Comment: That's a good question. Like I said above I'm going to be asking it the next chance I get. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when a real failure happens you usually get an exception...

IF you are really sure that you want to deal with this client-side (instead of optimizing the server-side for example by giving the server 128 GB of RAM) then you could

```
SqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0; // or an extremely high value
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) this represents "no timeout".

alternatively you can run this command on a connection opened with `context connection=true` in its connection string...

Comment: Setting the timeout to 0 certainly gets the job done, though it's too bad there isn't something a bit less brute force.

Answer (score -1):

Run it on appropriate hardware, no problem. Sorry, but a "server" has more than 64gb these days... and a table like that demands more than "a disc". Put some SSD in. THre is a limit on how far you can scale with "the disc" as you put it. People saying "the disc" often mean a low end server and the disc is not even a fast one (and no, a 7200 RPM disc is SLOW in the enterprise world, SAS discs go ot up 15k).

> It seems I'm getting the timeout on queries that return particularly large result sets, simply 
>   because it takes a while to transfer them over the network

How large are your data sets? Even half a million rows should not block it.

> Is there a better way to be doing this?

1gb network, 10gb network, Infiniband with 24gigabit. Increasing the timeout. This is a non issue - but I really would look at the numbers first. IIRC the timeout is 30 seconds and I fail to see you pulling so much data this is an issue here.